# Prove that: area of triangle $S_{ABC}=p \cdot R$, where p is half perimeter of triangle $DEF$

Tags: geometry

Prove that: area of triangle $S_{ABC}=p \cdot R$, where p is half perimeter of triangle $DEF$. $AD,CF, BE$ are altitudes. Is there a simple way?

[image]

Comment: (Though in view of the above link, the answers below may be more helpful, but you should clarify when asking your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$-orthocentre, $O$-circumcentre

$DE=HC\sin{\gamma}=2R\cos{\gamma}\sin{\gamma}=R\sin{2\gamma}$

Previous is because $HC$ is a diameter of the circumcircle of the triangle $HDE$.

Similar: 
$EF=R\sin{2\alpha}$ and
$DF=R\sin{2\beta}$

Therefore:
$p\cdot R=\frac{1}{2}R^2(\sin{2\alpha}+\sin{2\beta}+\sin{2\gamma})=S_{OBC}+S_{OAC}+S_{OAB}=S_{ABC}$